# ASP.NET MVC3: Which is the best method to implement listbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listbox, ienumerable, addition

I have a 'mylist' model entity which contains a IEnumerable field.

I'd like to populate 'mylist' and another to retreive possible elements, retreiving the elements from another mylist entity.
So, I would have two listboxes, one related to my 'mylist', the other one containing all the poexisting elements....
In particular I'd like to have the possibility put/remove elements using two add/remove buttons,  acting in the following way:

```
MYLIST FIELD             FULL MYLIST
##############          ###############
#  EL #1     #          #    EL #2    #
#  EL #3     #          #    EL #4    #
#            #   <--    #    EL #5    #
#            #   -->    #     ...     #
#            #          #    EL #n    #
##############          ###############
```

Could you give me some suggestions / examples, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the select input element with multi-select enabled in asp.net and in client side you can use many beautiful jquery select plugins.

Check out this plugin, it's very close to what you need http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/

And for a complete list check http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/multiple-select

Comment: Thank you very much @Jani! It is exactly what I was looking for! And jQuery Multiselect is really beautiful. THX!